# TipTap Menu Single Click

Tags: next.js, tiptap

I am using tiptap but somehow, to change text to bold, I need a double click.  But in the code as you can see, I am using onClick.  I wonder is there anyway that I can resolve this:

```
'use client'
import React, { useCallback, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import classnames from 'classnames'
import { is } from 'date-fns/locale'

import { EditorContent, useEditor } from '@tiptap/react';
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit';

import Strike from '@tiptap/extension-strike';
import Highlight from '@tiptap/extension-highlight';
import TextAlign from '@tiptap/extension-text-align';
import { Link } from '@tiptap/extension-link'
import Focus from '@tiptap/extension-focus';



const UpdateProfile = ({ user }: any) => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState(user.bio);

  const { data: session, status } = useSession()
  const [file, setFile] = useState<any>()
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState(null)
  const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState('')
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState<boolean | null>(null)
  const [isSuccess, setIsSuccess] = useState<boolean | null>(null)
  const [responded, setResponded] = useState(false)
  const [posting, setPosting] = useState(false)

  const [bio, setBio] = useState('')

  const btnRef = useRef(null)



  const handleAvatarUpdate = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('handling update 8430')
    setResponded(false)

    setPosting(true)

    const url = 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/setago/raw/upload'

    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', file)
    formData.append('upload_preset', 'setago')

    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    })

    const fileone = await res.json()

    // console.log('the file is: ')
    // console.log(fileone.secure_url)

    //get email when user is logged in
    if (status === 'authenticated') {
      // console.log('the email is: ')
      // console.log(session?.user?.email?.toString())
    }

    const response = await fetch('/api/user', {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: session?.user?.email?.toString(),
        avatar: avatar,
        avatarImg: fileone.secure_url,
      }),
    })

    // console.log('the response data')

    const data = await response.json()

    // console.log('the message is: ')
    // console.log(data.message)

    if (data.message === 'success') {
      setResponded(true)
      setSuccess(true)
      setPosting(false)
    } else {
      setResponded(true)
      setSuccess(false)
    }

    //the return data is a NextApiResponse
    // console.log(data)
    if (data.status === 200) {
      // console.log("it's 200")
      setPosting(false)
    } else {
      // console.log("it's not 200")
      setPosting(false)
    }
  }

  const handleAvatarImageChange = (event: any) => {
    setFile(event.target.files[0])

    // console.log('the event is: ')
    // console.log(event.target.files[0])

    for (var i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; ++i) {
      var name = event.target.files.item(i).name
      setFileName(name)
    }
  }

  const handleAvatarNameChange = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    // console.log('handling avatar change 8430')
    setAvatar(event.target.value)
  }

  let isValidInput = () => /^[a-zA-Z]{6,24}$/.test(avatar)

  const handleBioSubmit = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    // console.log('handling bio update 8430')

    const response = await fetch('/api/updatebio', {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        bio: editor?.getHTML(),
      }),
    })

    const data = await response.json()

    // console.log('the message is: ')

    // console.log(data.message)
    if (data.message === 'success') {
      setIsSuccess(true)
    }

  }

  const handleBioChange = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    // console.log('handling bio change 8430')
    if (content.length > 1000) {
      return
    }
    console.log("the content is: ")
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setContent(event.target.value)
  }

  const MenuBar = ({ editor, btnRef }: any) => {
    if (!editor) {
      return null;
    }

    const boldClick = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('the editor is: clicking bold')
      btnRef.current?.focus();
      editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run();
    };

    return (
      <div className='flex text-xs mt-2'>
        <button type='button' ref={btnRef}
          onClick={(e) => boldClick(e)}
          className={editor.isActive('bold') ? 'is-active' : ''}
        >
          <div className='px-2 border rounded-lg cursor-pointer'>
            bold
          </div>
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => editor.chain().focus().toggleItalic().run()}
          className={editor.isActive('italic') ? 'is-active' : ''}
        >
          <div className='ml-2 px-2 border rounded-lg'>
            italic
          </div>
        </button>

        <button onClick={setLink} className={editor.isActive('link') ? 'is-active' : ''}>
          <div className='ml-2 px-2 border rounded-lg'>
            link
          </div>
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => editor.chain().focus().unsetLink().run()}
          disabled={!editor.isActive('link')}
        >
          <div className='ml-2 px-2 border rounded-lg'>
            unlink
          </div>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [
      StarterKit,
      TextAlign.configure({
        types: ['heading', 'paragraph'],
      }),
      Focus.configure({
        className: 'focus',
      }),
      Highlight,
      Link.configure({
        openOnClick: false,
      }),
    ],
    editorProps: {
      attributes: {
        class: 'prose dark:prose-invert prose-sm sm:prose-base lg:prose-lg xl:prose-2xl mx-1 my-2 rounded border-2 focus:outline-none p-1',
      },
    },
    content: content.length < 500 ? content : content.slice(0, 800),
    autofocus: true,
    editable: true,
  });

  const setLink = useCallback(() => {
    const previousUrl = editor!.getAttributes('link').href
    const url = window.prompt('URL', previousUrl)

    // cancelled
    if (url === null) {
      return
    }

    // empty
    if (url === '') {
      editor!.chain().focus().extendMarkRange('link').unsetLink()
        .run()

      return
    }

    // update link
    editor!.chain().focus().extendMarkRange('link').setLink({ href: url })
      .run()
  }, [editor])

  if (!editor) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <div className='border rounded-sm p-2 pb-9' >
      <div className='text-2xl font-semibold py-1 underline'>
        Avatar And Profile
      </div>
      <div className='flex mb-6 text-2xl items-center'>
        <div>Avatar Name: </div>
        <div className='text-white'>A</div>
        <div className=''>{user.avatar}</div>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleAvatarUpdate}>
        <div className=''>
          <input
            type='file'
            id='uploadone'
            onChange={(event) => handleAvatarImageChange(event)}
            style={{ display: 'none' }}
            className='outline-0'
          />
          <label htmlFor='uploadone'>
            <div className='px-2 py-2 border-2 border-gray-900 bg-gray-100 rounded-xl text-gray-700 cursor-pointer w-64 h-12 text-start items-center'>
              <div className='flex justify-left'>
                <div className='w-8 h-8 relative'>
                  <Image
                    className='rounded-full border-2 border-green-800'
                    src={user.avatarImg}
                    alt=''
                    layout='fill'
                  />
                </div>
                <div className='text-xs md:text-base px-2 ml-1 mt-0.5'>
                  Select New Image
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </label>
          <input
            type='text'
            onChange={(event) => handleAvatarNameChange(event)}
            placeholder='NewAvatarName'
            className='placeholder:px-0 outline-1 border-2 border-gray-900 bg-gray-100 rounded-md text-gray-700 w-64 h-10 items-center mt-2'
            style={{ padding: '20px' }}
          />
          <div className='mt-2'>{success ? (
            <div>Avatar Updated</div>
          ) : (
            <div className='text-gray-400 text-sm'>
              {responded ? (
                <div className='text-red-400'>
                  Avatar name has been used, please enter a new name
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className='mt-2'>Enter a new avatar name.  Minimum 6 characters. Optional.</div>
              )}
            </div>
          )}</div>
          <div className='px-1 py-1  bg-gray-50 rounded-sm mx-2 mt-3 text-md w-64 text-slate-600'>
            {fileName}
          </div>
        </div>
        <button disabled={file ? !(avatar.length === 0 || (avatar.length >= 6 && isValidInput())) : !(avatar.length >= 6 && isValidInput())} value="Check Availability And Update">
          <div
            className="px-3 py-1 bg-slate-400 text-white rounded-md -mt-7 ml-4 lg:ml-0 text-sm hover:border-slate-600"
          >
            {posting ? 'Updating...' : 'Check Availability And Update'}
          </div>
        </button>
      </form>
      <div className='mt-12 underline text-gray-500'>Brief Bio</div>
      <div className='mt-0'>
        <div className='ml-6'>
          <MenuBar editor={editor} btnRef={btnRef} />
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={handleBioSubmit}>
          <EditorContent
            name="bio"
            // onChange={(event) => handleBioChange(event)}
            defaultValue={user?.bio ?? 'Bio'}
            // className='placeholder:px-0 outline-1 border-0 border-gray-900 bg-gray-100 rounded-md text-gray-700 w-2/3 h-24 items-center mt-2'
            // style={{ padding: '6px' }}
            editor={editor}
          >
          </EditorContent>
          <div className='text-white'>line</div>
          <button className='border-2 bg-green-600 px-3 py-1 rounded-lg text-white mt-0 hover:border-green-800'>Update Bio</button>
        </form>
        {isSuccess ? (
          <div>Bio Updated</div>
        ) : (
          <div></div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div >
  )
}

export default UpdateProfile
```